# How to dynamically update a particular list view item while using a ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

I am making a list view in Flutter. I want to update an item's property when the item is long pressed.

Following is the complete **Code:**

```
// main.dart
import 'package:LearnFlutter/MyList.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'MyList.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'List Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'My list demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: MyList(),
    );
  }
}

// MyList.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Item {
  Item(String name, bool selected, Color color) {
    _name = name;
    _selected = selected;
    _color = color;
  }

  String _name;
  bool _selected;
  Color _color;

  String getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  bool isSelected() {
    return _selected;
  }

  void toggleSelected() {
    _selected = !_selected;
  }

  void setColor(Color color) {
    _color = color;
  }

  Color getColor() {
    return _color;
  }
}

class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardyState createState() => new _CardyState();
}

class _CardyState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var itemsList = [
      Item('My item1', false, Colors.grey[200]),
      Item('My item2', false, Colors.grey[200]),
      Item('My item3', false, Colors.grey[200]),
    ];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.train),
            title: Text(itemsList[index].getName()),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            tileColor: itemsList[index].getColor(),
            selected: itemsList[index].isSelected(),
            onLongPress: () {
              toggleSelection(itemsList[index]);
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void toggleSelection(Item item) {
    print(item.getName() + ' long pressed');
    setState(() {
      item.toggleSelected();
      if (item.isSelected()) {
        item.setColor(Colors.blue[200]);
      } else {
        item.setColor(Colors.grey[200]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Question:**
In the above code `toggleSelection` is getting called on long press event. But the item's color does not get updated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: make `MyList` into a `stateless widget` keep all the data that it should show in the `HomePage` which is a statefull widget including the data abour the selected items. then pass the  data into `MyList`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. Is it possible for you to answer this out in code? I am anyways trying your solution but an answer with some code or some pseudocode would be clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason it is not functioning properly is that you have *no state* in your class `Item`, so you are not re-building/updating anything. If you would like to handle it there in the class, then you will need to extend it to the `ChangeNotifier`. You will also need to use the `ChangeNotifierProvider`, look at the docs for help: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

You will need the provider package: https://pub.dev/packages/provider

#### Class Item

```
class Item extends ChangeNotifier {
  Item(String name, Color color) {
    _name = name;
    _color = color;
  }

  int selectedIndex; // to know active index
  String _name;
  Color _color;

  String getName() {
    return _name;
  }

  void toggleSelected(int index) {
    selectedIndex = index;

    notifyListeners(); // To rebuild the Widget
  }

  void setColor(Color color) {
    _color = color;

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Color getColor() {
    return _color;
  }
}
```

#### Widget List

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardyState createState() => new _CardyState();
}

class _CardyState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = Provider.of<Item>(context); // Accessing the provider

    bool selected = false; // default val. of bool

    var itemsList = [
      Item('My item1', Colors.grey[200]),
      Item('My item2', Colors.grey[200]),
      Item('My item3', Colors.grey[200]),
    ];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemsList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
          child: ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.train),
            title: Text(itemsList[index].getName()),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
            tileColor: items.selectedIndex == index
                ? items.getColor()
                : Colors.grey[200],
            selected: items.selectedIndex == index ? true : false,
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() => selected = !selected);

              items.toggleSelected(index);

              if (selected) {
                items.setColor(Colors.red);
              }
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining out the root cause. Accepting the answer. I just have one question for my curiosity sake. I was hoping that I would have wrap the call to `toggleSelected` in `setState` but thats not what you did. Instead, this line of code `setState(() => selected = !selected)` looks like doing the trick. Why is `setColor` not wrapped in `setState`? Would you be kind enough to explain this little thing?

Comment: Hey there, of course, and no problem. Since I am changing the `state` of  `selected = !selected` in the Stateful widget itself, then I am allowed to use `setState` because this belongs to the state object. The reason I did not wrap `setColor ` in a `setState` is because I am already changing the *state* in the class by using `notifyListeners`. This is going to notify the stateful widget and rebuild it.

Comment: Aha! Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

make `MyList` into a stateless widget keep all the data that it should show in the `HomePage` which is a `statefull widget` including the data about the selected items. then pass the data into `MyList`

**here is how your MyList could be**

```dart
class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Item> items;
  final List<int> selectedItemIdList;
  final void Function(Item) onLongClick;

  MyList(this.items, this.selectedItemIdList, this.onLongClick);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, position) {
        //remember all you need to do here is to create your item based on the data you have
        var item = items[position];
        var isSelected = items.firstWhere((element) => item.id == element.id) != null;
        if (isSelected) {
          //build and return a widget with selected look
        } else {
          return GestureDetector(
            onLongPress: () => onLongClick(item), //changes data in homepage then MyList will be updated automatically
            child: Container(
              //rest of your widget
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      itemCount: items.length,
    );
  }
}
```

**inside your HomePageState**

```dart
//all the data the list it build from should be stored here not inside the list. and 

List<Item> items = [ ... ];
List<int> selectedItemIdList = [ ... ];

//MyList is just a Stateless widget that only shows this data change (a very DUMB view as one could say)

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MyList(items, selectedItemIdList, (item) { 
            setState((){
               selectedItemIdList.add(item.id);
            });
        });
  }
```

Comment: Do you reckon to have performance benefit on your answer compared to the other one by @Unbreachable?

Comment: I use this approach. What I found out is that Flutter is much smarter when it comes to drawing and redrawing in the lower level of code than classic frameworks like Android (native) and IOS. So I decided to only answer this question to myself if Flutter was not smart enough. meaning I had not performance problems yet. in other words I don't have an answer but it doesn't concern me either