# ListView.Builder not triggering a new Build and updating Widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

[image: Chart]

I have a very simple System. It basically consists on a Main View Model for a certain Screen, that creates children view model that are injected on some Child widgets.

That main View Model has the following properties that are relevant:

```
List<ChildrenViewModel> childrenViewModels;

int numberOfChildren() { return childrenViewModels.length; }

ChildrenViewModel childAt(int index) { return childrenViewModel[index]; }

void selectIfPossible(ChildrenViewModel child) { 
  //Business Logic to check if it is possible to select
  child.aCertainProperty.anotherProperty.selected = true;
  notifyObservers();
}
```

My main Widget does have a List.builder that looks like:

```
ListView.builder(
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: numberOfChildren(),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ChildWidget(
                  viewModel: viewModel.childAt(index));
            })
}
```

Now my ChildWidget is as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        viewModel.selectItem();
      },
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // a few widgets
          Image(
                    image: AssetImage(child.aCertainProperty.anotherProperty.selected
                        ? selectedImage
                        : unselectedImage)),
              ),
          // a few widgets
            ],
          ),
    );
```

The onTap, on my ChildViewModel, only does the following:

```
  void selectItem() {
    parentViewModel.selectIfPossible(this); //parentViewModel is the Main View Model on top
}
```

The theory is simple. A user taps a certain item on a list, some Business Logic is checked on the main View Model, then it notifies the observers that items were updated, and the List updates the items accordingly.

However this does not work at all. Debugging step by step I can see that the data in the view models is correct, but the ListView.Builder does never return updated widgets. Somehow, while using breakpoints, I can go step by step until `itemCount: numberOfChildren()` but it never ever advances to the Builder itself so it can return updated widgets. Does anyone have any tips on what I'm doing wrong and what I could. change to fix my issue?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried everything I can think of. The only way that it "works" is if I put the observer on the Widget that is the parent of the one that owns the ListView and force the entire tree of the ListView to be built. However by doing so the list does scroll back to the top, which is awful as UX.

Comment: Read this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76062477/7242912  It should solve your problem. You have to give the children, which you want to update a key also. Then you can answer your question by your self and accept it :)

Comment: Is `ChildWidget` a `StatelessWidget` or a `StatefulWidget`? And what is the superclass of your view model class?

Comment: @MrOrhan, I had looked at that thread as well, and while promising, I didn't manage to make it work like that. Unless I misunderstood the video, in my case, I should use an ObjectKey on the ChildWidget so that it knows what it is.

Comment: @Abion47, the child Widget is a `StatelessWidget` since my goal is to rebuild it completely, not change it. I have tried with a `StatefulWidget` as well, to no good results. As for the `Superclass`, my `ViewModel `looks like: ```class TextQuestionViewModel extends ChangeNotifier```.

Comment: You need a stateful widget to initiate changes, and it looks like the only stateful widget in your widget tree is the widget above the `ListView`. This will make it so the only way to rebuild the children widgets is to rebuild the `ListView` itself. If you want to update only the child widget, then you need to make the child widget stateful.

Comment: As an aside, you could be using Provider for this functionality. For example, a [`ChangeNotifierProvider`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) would automatically handle a lot of this boilerplate and subtleties. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549578/how-to-dynamically-update-a-particular-list-view-item-while-using-a-listview-bui

Comment: @Abion47, thanks. I checked and both the Widget that includes the ListViewBuilder and the Child, which I want to change, are already `ConsumerStatefulWidget` so the problem must be somewhere else/

Comment: If you're using riverpod (which is an important detail to include from the beginning, by the way), then you need to be listening to the provider at some point. Simply passing the view model to the child via the constructor isn't enough - it needs to be explicitly listening to it (for example, with `ref.watch` within the child widget build method). See: https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253971/discussion-between-flavio-silverio-and-abion47).

Comment: @Abion47, apologies, should have said I'm using Riverpod. I am watching the provider on the Build method, ie.: ```  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ref.watch(myProvider);
``` and that's what's triggering the build when my view model does `notifyObservers();`

Comment: In *which* build method?

Comment: @Abion47, just before the ListView. In this case: ```    TextQuestionButtonNotifier notifier = ref.watch(textQuestionButtonProvider); return ListView.builder( ... ```. The Build method itself fires, however the list items do not get rebuilt.

Comment: Then yeah, the widget that rebuilds the entire `ListView` is listening to changes, but not the list item widgets themselves. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your app right, you are updating only this on selected:

```
 Image(
                    image: AssetImage(child.aCertainProperty.anotherProperty.selected
                        ? selectedImage
                        : unselectedImage)),
              )
```

If its so, try to find a key, what you can Provide to it. Like the link in my Comment. You have to provide a unique key. But also the Widget which is holding the Image have to be Statefull!!!.

If you want to rebuild the whole Listview, you have to check for changes on the Widget, which is building ListView.builder. And then give every Item a unique key like :

```
...
 return ChildWidget(
                  key: const ValueKey('$index_changeInfo'),
                  viewModel: viewModel.childAt(index));
/// change info should be always different! Since the Value key
///informs it children wheter to change or not, it should change. if
///you have index as the key, it never changes, so the children will
///never notice they have to rebuild.
            })
...
```

But also here the Widget which is building the Listview has to be a statefull!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. They are all `Stateful` already. What I didn't understand is this line: `/// change info should be always different!` - What do you mean? The index where the child lies will no change. So if the child at index 0 needs to be `selected` I still have to pass the `viewModel.childAt[0];` to that item. Or is it something different?

Comment: I had mixed it up with valuekey(...) and childAt(...). I changed it and added also some more notes.